# Is a downstream/upstream dependency the same depender/dependee?

Tags: dependencies, terminology

Sometimes I read the phrase "downstream dependency/ies" and "upstream dependency/ies" of a software component.

When talking of a software component X, saying "X has a dependency" makes me think of something on which X depends, so why could this thing be "upstream" or "downstream"?

So maybe the point is that a "downstream dependency of X" is somethig that depends on X (so X would be the [depend-ee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee)), whereas "upstream dependency of X" is something which X depends on (so X would be the [depend-er](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/depender))?

Answer (score 0):

If your X component depend's of something, it's a upstream dependency.
If a component needs X, it's a downstream dependency for X component.

As much as the flow goes down, more features are added (value flow).